# SavingsAccount Program

Tags: java, oop, object

I am having a little bit of trouble with this program even though it COMPILES. It says that I must add a main method but however, I did that and I ended up getting 21 errors. Someone please help me..

Create a class SavingsAccount. Use a static class variable to store the annualInterestRate for each of the savers. Each object of the class contains a private instance variable savingsBalance indicating the amount the saver currently has on deposit. Provide method calculateMonthlyInterest to calculate the monthly interest by multiplying the balance by annualInterestRate divided by 12; this interest should be added to savingsBalance. Provide a static method modifyInterestRate that sets the annualInterestRate to a new value. Write a driver program to test the class SavingsAccount. Instantiate two different savingsAccount objects, saver1 and saver2, with balances of $2000.00 and $4000.00, respectively. Set annualInterestRate to 3%, then calculate the monthly interest and print the new balances for each of the savers. Then set the annualInterestRate to 5% and calculate the next months interest and print the new balances for each of the savers.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class SavingsAccount{

    private static double annualInterestRate;
    private double savingsBalance;

    public SavingsAccount()
    {
        savingsBalance = 0;
        annualInterestRate = 0;
    }

    public SavingsAccount(double balance)
    {
        savingsBalance = balance;
        annualInterestRate = 0;
    }

    public void calculateMonthlyInterest()
    {
        System.out.println("Current savings balance: " + savingsBalance);
        double monthlyInterest;
        monthlyInterest = (savingsBalance * annualInterestRate)/12;
        savingsBalance = monthlyInterest;
        System.out.println("New savings balance: " + savingsBalance);
    }

    public double getBalance()
    {
        return savingsBalance;
    }
    public static void modifyInterestRate(double newInterestRate)
    {
        annualInterestRate = newInterestRate;
    }
}
class Driver
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SavingsAccount saver1 = new SavingsAccount(2000);
        SavingsAccount saver2 = new SavingsAccount(4000);
        saver1.modifyInterestRate(.03);
        saver1.calculateMonthlyInterest();
        saver2.modifyInterestRate(.03);
        saver2.calculateMonthlyInterest();
        saver1.modifyInterestRate(.05);
        saver1.calculateMonthlyInterest();
        saver2.modifyInterestRate(.05);
        saver2.calculateMonthlyInterest();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please add the errors stack trace?

Comment: theres no errors, it can compile. But when it runs it says error theres no main method or something like that

Comment: Hello @Leonardo I check your code. It's working prefect you can see output in answer given by me.

Comment: Oh okay I totally forgot to make a seperate file for driver. Do I have to copy and paste my driver class into another java program and save it seperately?

Comment: no, Both class save as SavingsAccount.java in a file not separately and check my answer

Comment: it still gives me an error after I run it. I saved it SavingsAccount.java and the error still occurs.

Comment: still not working. what java your are using? maybe thats why it is working for you. Btw how do you mean run as java driver?

Answer (score 0):

Your code working perfect. Please save as `SavingsAccount.java` and `compile` using `javac SavingsAccount.java` and `run` using `java Driver`.

I `compile` and `run` your code and `output` is this

[image: Output]

Answer (score 0):

In `calculateMonthlyInterest()` you need to add the monthly interest to the savings balance rather than resetting the balance.  I.e.

```
    savingsBalance = monthlyInterest;
```

Should be:

```
    savingsBalance += monthlyInterest;
```

This the corrected `SavingsAccount` class should be:

```
public class SavingsAccount{

    private static double annualInterestRate;
    private double savingsBalance;

    public SavingsAccount()
    {
        savingsBalance = 0;
        annualInterestRate = 0;
    }

    public SavingsAccount(double balance)
    {
        savingsBalance = balance;
        annualInterestRate = 0;
    }

    public void calculateMonthlyInterest()
    {
        System.out.println("Current savings balance: " + savingsBalance);
        double monthlyInterest;
        monthlyInterest = (savingsBalance * annualInterestRate)/12;
        savingsBalance += monthlyInterest;
        System.out.println("New savings balance: " + savingsBalance);
    }

    public double getBalance()
    {
        return savingsBalance;
    }
    public static void modifyInterestRate(double newInterestRate)
    {
        annualInterestRate = newInterestRate;
    }
}
```

Comment: savingsBalance should sum the  monthly interest so that it would appear a correct answer;

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following code.

```
package savingsaccount;


public class SavingsAccount{

    private static double annualInterestRate;
    private double savingsBalance;

    public SavingsAccount()
    {
        savingsBalance = 0;
        annualInterestRate = 0;
    }

    public SavingsAccount(double balance)
    {
        savingsBalance = balance;
        annualInterestRate = 0;
    }

    public void calculateMonthlyInterest()
    {
        System.out.println("Current savings balance: " + savingsBalance);
        double monthlyInterest;
        monthlyInterest = (savingsBalance * annualInterestRate)/12;
        savingsBalance = monthlyInterest;
        System.out.println("New savings balance: " + savingsBalance);
    }

    public double getBalance()
    {
        return savingsBalance;
    }
    public static void modifyInterestRate(double newInterestRate)
    {
        annualInterestRate = newInterestRate;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SavingsAccount saver1 = new SavingsAccount(2000);
        SavingsAccount saver2 = new SavingsAccount(4000);
        SavingsAccount.modifyInterestRate(.03);
        saver1.calculateMonthlyInterest();
        SavingsAccount.modifyInterestRate(.03);
        saver2.calculateMonthlyInterest();
        SavingsAccount.modifyInterestRate(.05);
        saver1.calculateMonthlyInterest();
        SavingsAccount.modifyInterestRate(.05);
        saver2.calculateMonthlyInterest();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Put main method inside SavingsAccount class.

Like this,

```
public class SavingsAccount{

   private static double annualInterestRate;
    private double savingsBalance;

    public SavingsAccount()
    {
        savingsBalance = 0;
        annualInterestRate = 0;
    }

    public SavingsAccount(double balance)
    {
        savingsBalance = balance;
        annualInterestRate = 0;
    }

    public void calculateMonthlyInterest()
    {
        System.out.println("Current savings balance: " + savingsBalance);
        double monthlyInterest;
        monthlyInterest = (savingsBalance * annualInterestRate)/12;
        savingsBalance = monthlyInterest;
        System.out.println("New savings balance: " + savingsBalance);
    }

    public double getBalance()
    {
        return savingsBalance;
    }
    public static void modifyInterestRate(double newInterestRate)
    {
        annualInterestRate = newInterestRate;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SavingsAccount saver1 = new SavingsAccount(2000);
        SavingsAccount saver2 = new SavingsAccount(4000);
        saver1.modifyInterestRate(.03);
        saver1.calculateMonthlyInterest();
        saver2.modifyInterestRate(.03);
        saver2.calculateMonthlyInterest();
        saver1.modifyInterestRate(.05);
        saver1.calculateMonthlyInterest();
        saver2.modifyInterestRate(.05);
        saver2.calculateMonthlyInterest();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please my answer. It's work perfect no need to put main method put in ' SavingsAccount class '

Comment: Its still not working Like I do not know what you by saving the driver class in a different file